# javascript objects holding jquery objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I hold jquery objects as a key of javascript object somehow? (edited).. as a key..

```
var $a = $("#a");
var $b = $("#b");

var c = {};

c[$a] = foo;
c[$b] = bar;
```

Comment: Hey, you've changed the question! I've appended more info to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. jQuery objects are JavaScript objects.

```
var $a = $("#a");
var $b = $("#b");

var c = {};

c.foo = $a;
c.bar = $b;
```

As a key? No, you can't.

> A JavaScript object is a mapping between keys and values. **Keys are
>   strings** and values can be anything.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Objects